# coord_cartesian function in R has no effct on the plot

Tags: r

I am trying to gender distribution of a data set using a box plot in R.
This is the command:

```
qplot(x = gender, y = friendships_initiated,data = subset(pf, !is.na(gender)), geom = 'boxplot') + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 500))
```

There is no change in the y-axis. I have no idea why I get the following in the console:

```
ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord>
    aspect: function
    distance: function
    expand: TRUE
    is_linear: function
    labels: function
    limits: list
    range: function
    render_axis_h: function
    render_axis_v: function
    render_bg: function
    render_fg: function
    train: function
    transform: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord>
```

I get something similar when I use the scale_x_continuous function in another program.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it with `qplot`, you have to use the function `ggplot`

```
ggplot(subset(pf, !is.na(gender)), aes(gender, friendships_initiated)) + 
geom_boxplot() + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 500))
```